# Generalizing this jquery code

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to generalize this:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#target1').click(function() {
    $.post("process_form.php", $("#JqPostForm1").serialize(),
      function(data){
          $("#message_post1").html(data.reddit + " promoted!");
    }, "json");
  });
  $('#target2').click(function() {
    $.post("process_form.php", $("#JqPostForm2").serialize(),
      function(data){
          $("#message_post2").html(data.reddit + " promoted!</div>");
    }, "json");
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="message_post1">
  <form id="JqPostForm1">
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="pics" />
    <div id="target1">+</div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="message_post2">
  <form id="JqPostForm2">
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="documentaries" />
    <div id="target2">+</div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

for **message_post[1..1000]**, **JqPostForm[1..1000]**, **target[1..1000]** but there must be a better way than having 1000 jquery functions and maybe also a better way than having 1000 forms.

(the **process_form.php** just echoes back the value of the form)

I realize that this might be a bit too specific a question to begin with and for that you have my apologies.

**SOLVED** by you guys! Full solution:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.target').click(function() {
    var target = $(this);
    $.post("process_form.php", target.parent().serialize(),
      function(data){
        target.parent().html(data.reddit + " promoted!");
    }, "json");
  });
});
</script>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="pics" />
    <div class=target>+</div>
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="documentaries" />
    <div class=target>+</div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a class target to you targets and change your code to this

```
$('.target').click(function() {
  var target = $(this);
  $.post("process_form.php", target.parent().serialize(),
    function(data){
      target.parent().parent().html(data.reddit + " promoted!</div>");
  }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
function processForm($form, $msg) {
    $.post("process_form.php", $form.serialize(),
      function(data){
          $msg.html(data.reddit + " promoted!</div>");
    }, "json");
  }

$('.target').click(
    processForm($(this).closest('form'), $(this).closest('.messagePost'));
)


<div id="message_post1" class="messagePost">
  <form id="JqPostForm1">
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="pics" />
    <div id="target1" class="target">+</div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="message_post2" class="messagePost">
  <form id="JqPostForm2">
    <input type="hidden" name="reddit" value="documentaries" />
    <div id="target2" class="target">+</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the same function to all elements and parse the number out of it like this:

```
$('[id^=target]').click(function() {
  var number = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);
  $.post("process_form.php", $("#JqPostForm" + number).serialize(),
    function(data){
      $("#message_post" + number).html(data.reddit + " promoted!</div>");
    }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('div[id^=target]').click(function() {
    var current = this;
    $.post("process_form.php", $(this).parent().serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $(current).parent().parent().html(data.reddit + " promoted!</div>");
    }, "json");
});
```